# Qt Eclipse Integration: How to add a custom widget to UI once? (not to the designer menu)

Tags: eclipse, qt, eclipse-cdt

I'm using the Qt Eclipse integration and have written an own Widget (inherits `QWidget`) - is it possible to add the widget to the `.ui` (`.ui` file) without integrating it in the Qt C++ Widget Box menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found it on my own:

1. add base class widget (e.g. QWidget or whatever your own widget is derived from)
2. Open context menu of the widget in the "Qt C++ Object Inspector" view.
3. Click "Promote to .."
4. Create a "new promoted class"